# Formula stopped working after X rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, aggregate

I'm using this formula

```
IFERROR(INDEX('BEW'!$B$5:$B$2067;SMALL(IF('BEW'!$G$5:$G$2067=$B2;ROW('BEW'!$G$5:$G$2067)-ROW('BEW'!$G$5)+1);ROW($1:$1)));"")
```

For my excel form, It uses $B2 **, but for every number it changes ($J2, $B21, etc)** which in this example (second screenshot) is

```
188 B20 ZE 122011 1023
```

or

```
181 B20 ZE 122011 1024
```

Then it goes to this sheet in first screenshot and searches for corresponding number in G column and then list all numbers from B column:
[image: like here]

Everything is perfect till number 1023, after it, it suddenly stops listing.
Just like it had no values to list even though it has:
[image: here]

I checked formatting of table if it contains any unwanted symbols, nothing. Can formula have a limit?

My second form has the same issue but it lists one number per page instead of four.

Answer (score 0):

> **TL;DR:** Lose the **$** absolute row anchors in `ROW($1:$1)` like `ROW(1:1)` so that the row number **changes** as it is filled down. Lock the row number (not the column) in `$B2` with **$** as `B$2` so that it does **not change** as it is filled down.

You are returning an array of rows numbers containing matching *Nr teczki*. The [SMALL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) attempts to retrieve the *first, second, third, etc.* from these row numbers by incrementing its *k* parameter with the [ROW function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/ROW-function-3A63B74A-C4D0-4093-B49A-E76EB49A6D8D). e.g. If you put `=ROW(1:1)` in a cell and fill down, you get *1, 2, 3, etc.*. This would tell SMALL to retrieve the *first, second, third, etc.* matching row number.

However, you have locked the ROW function with **$** absolute row anchors. e.g. If you put `=ROW($1:$1)` in a cell and fill down, it retrieves *1, 1, 1, etc*  and SMALL retrieves the *first, first, first, etc.*

B2 contains your lookup value and for the exact opposite reason, you should lock the row number with `B$2`. You want to reference B2 and only B2 as you fill the formula down. While this could be `$B$2`, you may wish to leave the column relative to facilitate copying the formula into another column to the right.

Your array formula¹ with modifications:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(BEW!$B$5:$B$2067; SMALL(IF(BEW!$G$5:$G$2067=$B$2; ROW(BEW!$G$5:$G$2067)-ROW(BEW!$G$5)+1); ROW(1:1))); "")
```

[image: bew_small_index]
            <sup>[Sample Data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Formula%20stopped%20working%20after%20X%20rows.xlsx) and solution</sup>

**Addendum - more efficient and more universal**

As noted, array formulas chew up calculation logarithmically as their ranges increase. Keeping the ranges to the absolute minimum is essential in maximizing array formula efficiency.

```
'the following can be used to represent G2057:G2066
INDEX(G:G, 2057):INDEX(G:G, 2066)
```

Your data is grouped according to the *Numer teczki* in column G. Although it appears sorted, that is not guaranteed. If you can pull the row number of the first occurrence and the last occurrence of the lookup value in B2 you can use the syntax above to reference only the range that is relevant to the formula; this will greatly increase the efficiency of the formula.

The first row number is easy with a simple [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) and this alone would chop off a good deal of the non-relevant range. The latter would be similarly easy if the data in column G was sorted but that is not guaranteed. If it can be reasonably assumed that you will never have more than 100 entries for a single *Nr teczk* then we can just add 99 to the first result. This will still have some non-relevant rows of data but substantially less than searching the entire column.

```
'first row with '188 B20 ZE 122011 1023'
=MATCH(B$2, BEW!G:G, 0)
'last possible row with '188 B20 ZE 122011 1023'
=MATCH(B$2, BEW!G:G, 0)+99
'range for array formula
INDEX(BEW!G:G, MATCH(B$2, BEW!G:G, 0)):INDEX(BEW!G:G, MATCH(B$2, BEW!G:G, 0)+99)
```

If it can be reasonably assumed that you will never have more than 25 entries, change the 99 to 24. Be sure to leave some headroom in case the odd *Nr teczki* has an unusually large number of entries. Your array formula¹ becomes,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(BEW!$B:$B, SMALL(IF(INDEX(BEW!$G:$G, MATCH(B$2, BEW!$G:$G, 0)):INDEX(BEW!$G:$G, MATCH(B$2, BEW!$G:$G, 0)+99)=B$2, ROW(INDEX(BEW!$G:$G, MATCH(B$2, BEW!$G:$G, 0)):INDEX(BEW!$G:$G, MATCH(B$2, BEW!G:G, 0)+99))), ROW(1:1))), "")
'put a modern spin on it by substituting the SMALL function with the AGGREGATE² function
'this is a standard (non-array) formula
=IFERROR(INDEX(BEW!$B:$B, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(INDEX(BEW!$G:$G, MATCH(B$2, BEW!$G:$G, 0)):INDEX(BEW!$G:$G, MATCH(B$2, BEW!$G:$G, 0)+99))/(INDEX(BEW!$G:$G, MATCH(B$2, BEW!$G:$G, 0)):INDEX(BEW!$G:$G, MATCH(B$2, BEW!$G:$G, 0)+99)=B$2), ROW(1:1))), TEXT(,))
```

Fill down to catch all possible matches. Each of these formulas can be copied to the right for additional lookups. These dynamic range formula may look more complicated but they actually do a great deal less work unless you are willing to manually input the lookup range(s) for each *Nr teczki*.

[image: bew_small_index_lookup]
            <sup>[Sample Data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Formula%20stopped%20working%20after%20X%20rows.xlsx) and alternate formula solutions</sup>

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. If entered correctly, Excel with wrap the formula in braces (e.g. **{** and **}**). You do not type the braces in yourself. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

² <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Comment: First number is $B2, second number is $J2, third number is $B21 and fourth $J21, and so on, so can't lock it for one cell, the ROW function which is locked for every row is different, I made it up to 15 items so it's $1:$1, $2:$2...$15:$15, I locked it because when copying, it started to increment so for next page I had 40:40, 56:56 etc

Whole sheet is vertical which is about 82000 rows long

Comment: Please take a look at the [sample workbook](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Formula%20stopped%20working%20after%20X%20rows.xlsx) to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me -- VLOOKUP went about 1,000 rows, then returned 0 for everything, even when there was non-zero data in the spot being pointed to by the VLOOKUP.

How I fixed this makes no sense (to me).  The VLOOKUPS were looking out as far as 34 columns from the lookup value.  In desperation I rearranged the target sheet so that the column index numbers were much smaller, and for whatever reason, that worked.

Strange.